# Prove the function is integrable

Tags: integration, proof-verification

For a point $x \in [1,2]$, define $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational and define $f(x)= \frac 1n$ if $x$ is rational and is expressed as $x = \frac mn$ for natural numbers $m$ & $n$ having no common positive integer divisor other than $1$. Prove that the function $f:[1,2] \to \mathbb R$ is integrable. (Hint: first prove that given $ \epsilon > 0$, there are only a finite number of points $x$ in the interval $[1,2]$ at which $f(x) \geq \epsilon$)

I have no idea how to start or what to do with the hint... I figure the rationals are dense so this should mean that there are an infinite number of points in $[1,2]$ which are rational of the form $\frac mn$. So why would there be a finite number of points at which $f(x) \geq \epsilon$?

Comment: First check what integral concept is used.